# Desaturate shadows in Lightworks

Tags: color-correction, color-grading, lightworks

I'm using Lightworks as my main video editor (I use Blender occasionally), and use it to color grade too. I want to desaturate my shadows using either Lightworks or Blender, but I can't find that tool. Is it there, and if it's not, is it on something else I can use on my Linux system (not Resolve, needs very specific hardware i can't afford)? LUTs that do this are an option too!

Thnx ahead :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Lightworks, there's the selective color correction tool.
By moving the sliders like this you can select the shadows (luma slider) and desaturate them:
[image]

By  clicking "Reveal" you can see which parts of the image are going to be changed.
With much thanks to the guys at the Lightworks forum.
Source: [Lightworks forum: Desaturate shadows](http://www.lwks.com/index.php?option=com_kunena&func=view&catid=7&id=104681&Itemid=81#104813)

Answer (score 0):

Neither Lightworks nor Blender really offer any coloring functionality advanced enough to do that natively. However, Davinci Resolve is a free program which has very advanced color grading functionality which will allow you to easily desaturate shadows. It also isn't that complicated of a program. It can be difficult to understand all the ins and outs, but basic functions are very intuitive.

Comment: As stated in my question, resolve is not an option for me because I'm on a linux system and the free version is only for Mac and Windows